# Cann't build libvpx on Windows 7 x32

Tags: windows-7, libvpx

I download libvpx from code.google.com
I want to use libvpx with Qt4.8.
I followed by http://www.webmproject.org/code/build-prerequisites/  but everytime failed.
When I run ./configure in cygwin I get that:

```
Configuring selected codecs
  enabling vp8_encoder
  enabling vp8_decoder
Configuring for target 'x86-win32-gcc'
  enabling x86
  enabling runtime_cpu_detect
  enabling mmx
  enabling sse
  enabling sse2
  enabling sse3
  enabling ssse3
  enabling sse4_1
  using yasm
  enabling postproc
Unable to invoke compiler: gcc  -fno-common -m32

Configuration failed. This could reflect a misconfiguration of your
toolchains, improper options selected, or another problem. If you
don't see any useful error messages above, the next step is to look
at the configure error log file (config.err) to determine what
configure was trying to do when it died.
```

And in config.err:

```
# ./configure 
Configuring selected codecs
  enabling vp8_encoder
  enabling vp8_decoder
Configuring for target 'x86-win32-gcc'
  enabling x86
check_cpp
BEGIN /tmp/vpx-conf-2784-12342.c
END /tmp/vpx-conf-2784-12342.c
-o /tmp/vpx-conf-2784-20403.o /tmp/vpx-conf-2784-12342.c
./build/make/configure.sh: line 281: -E: команда не найдена
  enabling runtime_cpu_detect
  enabling mmx
  enabling sse
  enabling sse2
  enabling sse3
  enabling ssse3
  enabling sse4_1
check_cxxflags -fomit-frame-pointer
check_cxx -Werror -fomit-frame-pointer
BEGIN /tmp/vpx-conf-2784-12342.c
END /tmp/vpx-conf-2784-12342.c
g++ -fno-common -m32 -Werror -fomit-frame-pointer -c -o /tmp/vpx-conf-2784-20403.o /tmp/vpx-conf-2784-12342.c
g++.exe: /tmp/vpx-conf-2784-12342.c: No such file or directory
g++.exe: no input files
check_cflags -fomit-frame-pointer
check_cc -fomit-frame-pointer
BEGIN /tmp/vpx-conf-2784-12342.c
END /tmp/vpx-conf-2784-12342.c
gcc -fno-common -m32 -fomit-frame-pointer -c -o /tmp/vpx-conf-2784-20403.o /tmp/vpx-conf-2784-12342.c
gcc.exe: /tmp/vpx-conf-2784-12342.c: No such file or directory
gcc.exe: no input files
  using yasm
check_cxxflags -O3
check_cxx -Werror -O3
BEGIN /tmp/vpx-conf-2784-12342.c
END /tmp/vpx-conf-2784-12342.c
g++ -fno-common -m32 -Werror -O3 -c -o /tmp/vpx-conf-2784-20403.o /tmp/vpx-conf-2784-12342.c
g++.exe: /tmp/vpx-conf-2784-12342.c: No such file or directory
g++.exe: no input files
check_cflags -O3
check_cc -O3
BEGIN /tmp/vpx-conf-2784-12342.c
END /tmp/vpx-conf-2784-12342.c
gcc -fno-common -m32 -O3 -c -o /tmp/vpx-conf-2784-20403.o /tmp/vpx-conf-2784-12342.c
gcc.exe: /tmp/vpx-conf-2784-12342.c: No such file or directory
gcc.exe: no input files
check_cc
BEGIN /tmp/vpx-conf-2784-12342.c
END /tmp/vpx-conf-2784-12342.c
gcc -fno-common -m32 -c -o /tmp/vpx-conf-2784-20403.o /tmp/vpx-conf-2784-12342.c
gcc.exe: /tmp/vpx-conf-2784-12342.c: No such file or directory
gcc.exe: no input files
check_header pthread.h
check_cpp
BEGIN /tmp/vpx-conf-2784-12342.c
END /tmp/vpx-conf-2784-12342.c
gcc -fno-common -m32 -E -o /tmp/vpx-conf-2784-20403.o /tmp/vpx-conf-2784-12342.c
gcc.exe: /tmp/vpx-conf-2784-12342.c: No such file or directory
gcc.exe: no input files
check_header unistd.h
check_cpp
BEGIN /tmp/vpx-conf-2784-12342.c
END /tmp/vpx-conf-2784-12342.c
gcc -fno-common -m32 -E -o /tmp/vpx-conf-2784-20403.o /tmp/vpx-conf-2784-12342.c
gcc.exe: /tmp/vpx-conf-2784-12342.c: No such file or directory
gcc.exe: no input files
check_cxxflags -Wall
check_cxx -Werror -Wall
BEGIN /tmp/vpx-conf-2784-12342.c
END /tmp/vpx-conf-2784-12342.c
g++ -fno-common -m32 -Werror -Wall -c -o /tmp/vpx-conf-2784-20403.o /tmp/vpx-conf-2784-12342.c
g++.exe: /tmp/vpx-conf-2784-12342.c: No such file or directory
g++.exe: no input files
check_cflags -Wall
check_cc -Wall
BEGIN /tmp/vpx-conf-2784-12342.c
END /tmp/vpx-conf-2784-12342.c
gcc -fno-common -m32 -Wall -c -o /tmp/vpx-conf-2784-20403.o /tmp/vpx-conf-2784-12342.c
gcc.exe: /tmp/vpx-conf-2784-12342.c: No such file or directory
gcc.exe: no input files
check_cxxflags -Wdeclaration-after-statement
check_cxx -Werror -Wdeclaration-after-statement
BEGIN /tmp/vpx-conf-2784-12342.c
END /tmp/vpx-conf-2784-12342.c
g++ -fno-common -m32 -Werror -Wdeclaration-after-statement -c -o /tmp/vpx-conf-2784-20403.o /tmp/vpx-conf-2784-12342.c
g++.exe: /tmp/vpx-conf-2784-12342.c: No such file or directory
g++.exe: no input files
check_cflags -Wdeclaration-after-statement
check_cc -Wdeclaration-after-statement
BEGIN /tmp/vpx-conf-2784-12342.c
END /tmp/vpx-conf-2784-12342.c
gcc -fno-common -m32 -Wdeclaration-after-statement -c -o /tmp/vpx-conf-2784-20403.o /tmp/vpx-conf-2784-12342.c
gcc.exe: /tmp/vpx-conf-2784-12342.c: No such file or directory
gcc.exe: no input files
check_cxxflags -Wdisabled-optimization
check_cxx -Werror -Wdisabled-optimization
BEGIN /tmp/vpx-conf-2784-12342.c
END /tmp/vpx-conf-2784-12342.c
g++ -fno-common -m32 -Werror -Wdisabled-optimization -c -o /tmp/vpx-conf-2784-20403.o /tmp/vpx-conf-2784-12342.c
g++.exe: /tmp/vpx-conf-2784-12342.c: No such file or directory
g++.exe: no input files
check_cflags -Wdisabled-optimization
check_cc -Wdisabled-optimization
BEGIN /tmp/vpx-conf-2784-12342.c
END /tmp/vpx-conf-2784-12342.c
gcc -fno-common -m32 -Wdisabled-optimization -c -o /tmp/vpx-conf-2784-20403.o /tmp/vpx-conf-2784-12342.c
gcc.exe: /tmp/vpx-conf-2784-12342.c: No such file or directory
gcc.exe: no input files
check_cxxflags -Wpointer-arith
check_cxx -Werror -Wpointer-arith
BEGIN /tmp/vpx-conf-2784-12342.c
END /tmp/vpx-conf-2784-12342.c
g++ -fno-common -m32 -Werror -Wpointer-arith -c -o /tmp/vpx-conf-2784-20403.o /tmp/vpx-conf-2784-12342.c
g++.exe: /tmp/vpx-conf-2784-12342.c: No such file or directory
g++.exe: no input files
check_cflags -Wpointer-arith
check_cc -Wpointer-arith
BEGIN /tmp/vpx-conf-2784-12342.c
END /tmp/vpx-conf-2784-12342.c
gcc -fno-common -m32 -Wpointer-arith -c -o /tmp/vpx-conf-2784-20403.o /tmp/vpx-conf-2784-12342.c
gcc.exe: /tmp/vpx-conf-2784-12342.c: No such file or directory
gcc.exe: no input files
check_cxxflags -Wtype-limits
check_cxx -Werror -Wtype-limits
BEGIN /tmp/vpx-conf-2784-12342.c
END /tmp/vpx-conf-2784-12342.c
g++ -fno-common -m32 -Werror -Wtype-limits -c -o /tmp/vpx-conf-2784-20403.o /tmp/vpx-conf-2784-12342.c
g++.exe: /tmp/vpx-conf-2784-12342.c: No such file or directory
g++.exe: no input files
check_cflags -Wtype-limits
check_cc -Wtype-limits
BEGIN /tmp/vpx-conf-2784-12342.c
END /tmp/vpx-conf-2784-12342.c
gcc -fno-common -m32 -Wtype-limits -c -o /tmp/vpx-conf-2784-20403.o /tmp/vpx-conf-2784-12342.c
gcc.exe: /tmp/vpx-conf-2784-12342.c: No such file or directory
gcc.exe: no input files
check_cxxflags -Wcast-qual
check_cxx -Werror -Wcast-qual
BEGIN /tmp/vpx-conf-2784-12342.c
END /tmp/vpx-conf-2784-12342.c
g++ -fno-common -m32 -Werror -Wcast-qual -c -o /tmp/vpx-conf-2784-20403.o /tmp/vpx-conf-2784-12342.c
g++.exe: /tmp/vpx-conf-2784-12342.c: No such file or directory
g++.exe: no input files
check_cflags -Wcast-qual
check_cc -Wcast-qual
BEGIN /tmp/vpx-conf-2784-12342.c
END /tmp/vpx-conf-2784-12342.c
gcc -fno-common -m32 -Wcast-qual -c -o /tmp/vpx-conf-2784-20403.o /tmp/vpx-conf-2784-12342.c
gcc.exe: /tmp/vpx-conf-2784-12342.c: No such file or directory
gcc.exe: no input files
check_cxxflags -Wimplicit-function-declaration
check_cxx -Werror -Wimplicit-function-declaration
BEGIN /tmp/vpx-conf-2784-12342.c
END /tmp/vpx-conf-2784-12342.c
g++ -fno-common -m32 -Werror -Wimplicit-function-declaration -c -o /tmp/vpx-conf-2784-20403.o /tmp/vpx-conf-2784-12342.c
g++.exe: /tmp/vpx-conf-2784-12342.c: No such file or directory
g++.exe: no input files
check_cflags -Wimplicit-function-declaration
check_cc -Wimplicit-function-declaration
BEGIN /tmp/vpx-conf-2784-12342.c
END /tmp/vpx-conf-2784-12342.c
gcc -fno-common -m32 -Wimplicit-function-declaration -c -o /tmp/vpx-conf-2784-20403.o /tmp/vpx-conf-2784-12342.c
gcc.exe: /tmp/vpx-conf-2784-12342.c: No such file or directory
gcc.exe: no input files
check_cxxflags -Wuninitialized
check_cxx -Werror -Wuninitialized
BEGIN /tmp/vpx-conf-2784-12342.c
END /tmp/vpx-conf-2784-12342.c
g++ -fno-common -m32 -Werror -Wuninitialized -c -o /tmp/vpx-conf-2784-20403.o /tmp/vpx-conf-2784-12342.c
g++.exe: /tmp/vpx-conf-2784-12342.c: No such file or directory
g++.exe: no input files
check_cflags -Wuninitialized
check_cc -Wuninitialized
BEGIN /tmp/vpx-conf-2784-12342.c
END /tmp/vpx-conf-2784-12342.c
gcc -fno-common -m32 -Wuninitialized -c -o /tmp/vpx-conf-2784-20403.o /tmp/vpx-conf-2784-12342.c
gcc.exe: /tmp/vpx-conf-2784-12342.c: No such file or directory
gcc.exe: no input files
check_cxxflags -Wunused-variable
check_cxx -Werror -Wunused-variable
BEGIN /tmp/vpx-conf-2784-12342.c
END /tmp/vpx-conf-2784-12342.c
g++ -fno-common -m32 -Werror -Wunused-variable -c -o /tmp/vpx-conf-2784-20403.o /tmp/vpx-conf-2784-12342.c
g++.exe: /tmp/vpx-conf-2784-12342.c: No such file or directory
g++.exe: no input files
check_cflags -Wunused-variable
check_cc -Wunused-variable
BEGIN /tmp/vpx-conf-2784-12342.c
END /tmp/vpx-conf-2784-12342.c
gcc -fno-common -m32 -Wunused-variable -c -o /tmp/vpx-conf-2784-20403.o /tmp/vpx-conf-2784-12342.c
gcc.exe: /tmp/vpx-conf-2784-12342.c: No such file or directory
gcc.exe: no input files
check_cxxflags -Wunused-but-set-variable
check_cxx -Werror -Wunused-but-set-variable
BEGIN /tmp/vpx-conf-2784-12342.c
END /tmp/vpx-conf-2784-12342.c
g++ -fno-common -m32 -Werror -Wunused-but-set-variable -c -o /tmp/vpx-conf-2784-20403.o /tmp/vpx-conf-2784-12342.c
g++.exe: /tmp/vpx-conf-2784-12342.c: No such file or directory
g++.exe: no input files
check_cflags -Wunused-but-set-variable
check_cc -Wunused-but-set-variable
BEGIN /tmp/vpx-conf-2784-12342.c
END /tmp/vpx-conf-2784-12342.c
gcc -fno-common -m32 -Wunused-but-set-variable -c -o /tmp/vpx-conf-2784-20403.o /tmp/vpx-conf-2784-12342.c
gcc.exe: /tmp/vpx-conf-2784-12342.c: No such file or directory
gcc.exe: no input files
check_cxxflags -Wno-unused-function
check_cxx -Werror -Wno-unused-function
BEGIN /tmp/vpx-conf-2784-12342.c
END /tmp/vpx-conf-2784-12342.c
g++ -fno-common -m32 -Werror -Wno-unused-function -c -o /tmp/vpx-conf-2784-20403.o /tmp/vpx-conf-2784-12342.c
g++.exe: /tmp/vpx-conf-2784-12342.c: No such file or directory
g++.exe: no input files
check_cflags -Wno-unused-function
check_cc -Wno-unused-function
BEGIN /tmp/vpx-conf-2784-12342.c
END /tmp/vpx-conf-2784-12342.c
gcc -fno-common -m32 -Wno-unused-function -c -o /tmp/vpx-conf-2784-20403.o /tmp/vpx-conf-2784-12342.c
gcc.exe: /tmp/vpx-conf-2784-12342.c: No such file or directory
gcc.exe: no input files
  enabling postproc
check_cxx
BEGIN /tmp/vpx-conf-2784-12342.c
END /tmp/vpx-conf-2784-12342.c
g++ -fno-common -m32 -c -o /tmp/vpx-conf-2784-20403.o /tmp/vpx-conf-2784-12342.c
g++.exe: /tmp/vpx-conf-2784-12342.c: No such file or directory
g++.exe: no input files
check_header stdio.h
check_cpp
BEGIN /tmp/vpx-conf-2784-12342.c
END /tmp/vpx-conf-2784-12342.c
gcc -fno-common -m32 -E -o /tmp/vpx-conf-2784-20403.o /tmp/vpx-conf-2784-12342.c
gcc.exe: /tmp/vpx-conf-2784-12342.c: No such file or directory
gcc.exe: no input files
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Works. I set system paths

Comment: Hi. I'm facing a similar issue. Can you elaborate on "set system paths"?